# Rails render not refrshing the page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on ROR app . The app view contain ajax and jquery code :

```
jQuery.ajax({
  data:     'val=' + val,
  dataType: 'script',
  type:     'post',
  url:      "/portfolio/update"
});
```

The update action contain this code:

```
def update
  j = params[:val]

  # Buisness logic code
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "update done"
end
```

current View and Root url is same - Portfolio/show
Now the button on view (which is root_url only)is doing the business logic fine , but the page is not getting refreshed , Whereas other simple form button on views are doing it. After pressing button i am getting this in rails server:

```
Rendered portfolio/show.erb (1.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 4.1ms)
```

Any guesses, but the page is not refreshing by its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is used to provide functionality where page refresh is not desired. If you want page refresh, then you should rather use html form and submit button.

```
  <%= form_for %>
   .....
  <% submit %>
```

or with Ajax, you need to do it manually on success call back,

like this,

```
$.ajax({

 success: function(){
  window.location.reload();
 }
);
```

Comment: Basically using ajax i am calling my action which is updating my database then i had to refresh my page to show the updated data on the same page. I am started in ajax can you plz elaborate.

Comment: it should be window.location.reload()

Answer (score 1):

No guess needed. Your controller responded with wrong type.

`redirect_to` can only work under html response. When your request type is 'script' which is 'js', nothing can be rendered.

To correct it

```
def update
  # blah blah
  respond_to |format|
    format.html { redirect_to some_path }
    format.js # This will render default js template views/portfolio/update.js.erb
  end
end
```

Then prepare the js template

```
$('#div_to_update').html('new html code to update the view')
```

Comment: It doesn't refresh the page. you forgot to add do to your code. Rails s output: Rendered portfolio/update.js.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 1.6ms)

Comment: @DeependerSingla, reload page is not something nice if using JS, update div is preferred. For example you vote an answer here, the page is not refreshed but vote count increased. But you can still add whatever js code you need in the js template, say `windows.location.reload();` as maximus suggested.

Comment: What Billy said is perfect. Reading some Ajax basics will help you learn faster. Here is one awesome side http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp